# how to ignore duplicates when I insert many records at once?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to insert into a many to many table, the ID1 and ID2, where ID1 is always the same value and I have many ID2.

I can use this query:

```
insert into MyTable (ID1, ID2) 
    select 1, ID
    from AnotherTable
    where ID in (1, 2, 3);
```

But if ID1 is related with some of the ID2, I get an error because of unique constraint. So i would like to know how it would be the way to ignore the duplicate values and insert the rest of the rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you select a duplicate, or is a row you are trying to insert already present in the target table?

Comment: it is a duplicate that is in the target table. I mean, I have for example (1,1) and (1,3) values in the target tablet and I am trying to insert (1,1), (1,2) and (1,3). I want that at the end, (1,2) is inserted and don't get an error because of (1,1) and (1,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EXCEPT` operator for this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID1, ID2) 
SELECT 1, ID
FROM AnotherTable
WHERE ID in (1, 2, 3)

EXCEPT

SELECT ID1,ID2
FROM MyTable ;
```